# Градиент как фон у текста

Tags: html, css

Как сделать фоновый градиент такого плана?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это должен быть один блок, вроде h1, с вложенным span(если нужен), но разделять каждую строку на отдельные блоки -нельзя.

Comment: не плохо было бы показать, что уже пробовал

Comment: Свой код показывайте, а то уже начали вопрос закрывать :P

Comment: Вот здесь предложено несколько вариантов https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/

Comment: @Heidel, к сожалению эти варианты не подходят, одни только для однородного фона, другие с использованием js и все равно выводят независимые друг от друга градиенты у каждой строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужного эффекта можно добиться при помощи свойств `box-decoration-break: clone` вместе с регулированием `background-size`. Поддержка такого решения браузерами на уровне 90% (с префиксами).

```css
p {
  max-width: 600px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: Arial;
  line-height: 67px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

p span {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black, red);
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  background-size: 600px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 7px 20px;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Привет, подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему</span></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Так пойдёт?

```css
.gradient-test {
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 0, #F00 500pt); 
 font-family: sans-serif; 
 font-size: 24pt; 
        line-height: 100%;
 color: white; 
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<span class="gradient-test">ПРИВЕТ, ПОДСКАЖИТЕ</span><br>
<span class="gradient-test">ПОЖАЛУЙСТА КАК РЕШИТЬ</span><br>
<span class="gradient-test">ПРОБЛЕМУ</span>
```

Comment: К сожалению -нет, текст разделять по блокам никак нельзя(

Answer (score -1):

Так сделать нельзя на ваших условиях.

Вырезайте картинку, в этом нет ничего зазорного.

Comment: я бы так и сделал, но остается проблема мультиязычности, размеры текстов могут быть разные, а соответствие дизайну должно быть 100%.
Так же пострадает "кросс-браузерность\платформенность" т.к. почти все рендерят текст по своему и нужно учитывать добавления полупикселей в том же сафари и т.п. а значит градиентный фон должен определяться размером текста.

Comment: Значит либо вам понадобится сделать много много картинок, либо придется разбивать текст на кусочки.

А вообще, я бы попробовал объяснить дизайнеру сложность эффекта и попросил найти другое решение для оформления

Comment: Ответ немного устарел, уже можно :-)